# Как выполнить groovy скрипт из bat файла?

Tags: bat, groovy

У меня в отдельном файле проекта есть groovy скрипт, выполняющий определённые действия. Я хочу запускать этот скрипт с помощью bat файла. С помощью какой команды и как это сделать?

Как советовали, пробовал `groovy script.groovy`, но непонятно почему выдаётся следующая ошибка:

```
C:\Users\User>cd IdeaProjects\Task\src\main\java

C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\Task\src\main\java>groovy task.groovy
Caught: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
        at task.run(task.groovy:9)
```

Да, в моём скрипте есть подключение к бд с помощью `org.postgresql.Driver`:

```
sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:postgresql://" + addrDB + nameDB, userDB, passDB, "org.postgresql.Driver")
```

Но почему скрипт запускается и нормально работает из IDE (с точно такой же строчкой), но не запускается из командной строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если groovy есть в PATH, просто

```
groovy script.groovy
```

кладете эту строку в новый текстовый файл, сохраняете его с расширением .bat и запускаете в той же папке, где скрипт лежит. Иначе

```
"путь к groovy\groovy.exe" "путь к скрипту\script.groovy"
```

Если у вас используются русские имена в пути, не забудьте в начале bat-файла написать

```
chcp 1251
```

смена кодировки.

Comment: groovy есть в PATH. Я попытался сделать, как вы сказали - описал проблему в вопросе (см. выше)

Comment: Из содержания скрипта будет яснее. У меня ощущение, что зависимость postgresql не удовлетворена: IDE кладет его в classpath, а без IDE нужно как-то этот classpath прописать отдельно. Не видит, потому что не указано, где его искать.

Comment: Danny, я решил это с помощью следующих 2-ух строк: `@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true);
@Grab(group='org.postgresql', module='postgresql', version='9.4-1205-jdbc42')`. Но теперь bat файл выполняет скрипт, а IDE перестала. Пишет: `Groovyc: While compiling Task: Cannot @Grab without Ivy, please add it to your module dependencies (NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/report/ResolveReport)`. Как это поправить?

Comment: Добавил в ответ dependency для Ivy.

Comment: Danny, помогло, спасибо за помощь!!

Comment: Пожалуйста! Если вас устраивает ответ, вы можете выбрать его, поставив под ним зеленую галочку.

Answer (score 1):

Для нормальной работы батника, чтобы подключиться к бд с помощью `org.postgresql.Driver` мне помогли следующие строчки:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab(group='org.postgresql', module='postgresql', version='9.4-1205-jdbc42')
sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:postgresql://" + addrDB + nameDB, userDB, passDB, "org.postgresql.Driver")
```

После этого скрипт начинает корректно работать, если вызывать его из bat файла, однако перестаёт корректно работать из IDE, выдавая следующее:

```
Groovyc: While compiling Task: Cannot @Grab without Ivy, please add it to your module dependencies (NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/report/ResolveReport)
```

Решить это мне помог @Danny, указав как добавить ivy в pom.xml:

```
<dependency>  <!-- support @Grab in Groovy scripts -->
    <groupId>org.apache.ivy</groupId>
    <artifactId>ivy</artifactId>  
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

После этого всё хорошо запускается и из батника, и из IDE!